# How to store directories in Git that contain Git repositories?

Tags: git

Is there a preferred Git technique for managing a local repository that may contain other third-party repositories?  I keep my "dot" files like .bashrc, .bash_aliases, and .vimrc in a "dotfiles" subdirectory ~/dotfiles.  I also have a .vim subdirectory in dotfiles that contains many third-party bundles which themselves contain Git repos.  As a consequence, when I try to add files before I perform a commit on dotfiles, I see many entries like the following:

```
modified:   .vim.snipmate/bundle/Vundle.vim (modified content)
modified:   .vim.snipmate/bundle/tlib_vim (modified content)
modified:   .vim.snipmate/bundle/vim-addon-mw-utils (modified content)
modified:   .vim.snipmate/bundle/vim-snipmate (modified content)
modified:   .vim.snipmate/bundle/vim-snippets (modified content)
modified:   .vim.ultisnips/bundle/Vundle.vim (modified content)
```

There are a couple of ways around this such as putting these subdirectories in .gitignore or creating a script that deletes the .git subdirectories.  But both aren't very good options as I'd have to remember to do something when I add a new Vim plugin.  Does Git provide a standard way to handle this situation?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Thanks!  That's given me a good direction to research.  I can now see there are a number of articles on submodules and Vim.  If you want to submit this as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [*Git Submodules*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

I haven't used them in years but it seems to be the idiomatic way of working with multiple repositories with overlapping source trees. In essence, submodules allow you to treat Git repositories as sub-directories of other Git repositories.